# Strange issue with 64 bit OS

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit

So I own two versions of Windows 7, one is 32 bit, the other is 64.

The 64 bit version came with my new desktop, and the 32 bit version came with my Laptop.

I was doing a clean install of my laptop, and the install went smooth, Windows is up and running!

However, after installing it I realized that I accidentally used the 64 bit installation disk instead of the 32 bit version. I confirmed this in the System Information screen, it says:

System type: 64-bit Operating System

As far as I knew this laptop was only a 32 bit machine. My understanding is that a 64 bit OS would NOT run on 32 bit architecture. Am I correct with this assumption?

If this was a 32 bit laptop is there any way a 64 bit OS would even run at all on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I was able to find the specs for the computer, and I looked up the processor. Apparently it is a 64 bit machine, but for some reason it came with a 32 bit OS. So it should be able to run Windows 7 x64 without any problems.

Comment: Glad you solved it!

Comment: If you don't have more than 3 GB RAM installed, no point installing the 64-bit version as it'll only take up more space.

Comment: Karan, thanks for the info. Right now there is 1.5GB of RAM, however I am planning on upgrading the RAM soon anyways.

Answer (score 1):

With me also something like this happened. I installed 64-bit Windows 7 on my 32-bit processor and it installed successfully. It ran 1 or 2 times and then the error came that my processor is not 64-bit compatible. So now I am unable to use it. But this wasn't the same with Windows 8 64-bit. It didn't install at all.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that it worked perfectly fine a couple of times, and then stopped? Or were there funny things happening the couple of times it did work?

Comment: It worked perfectly fine initially and then didnt start at all. There were no funny things.

Comment: @SherwinFlight How did you check that your processor is 64-bit compatible?

Comment: I found the specs for the computer, and it said the type of processor it was. I looked up that processor and it said it supported 64 bit.